# Storing entities with a OneToOne mapping with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys

I have the following two entities:

Person.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person", optional = false)
    private Address address;

    public Person(final String firstName, final String lastName, final Address address)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    //Required by hibernate
    public Person()
    {
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setId(final int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(final String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(final String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setAddress(final Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Address.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address
{
    @Id
    private int personId;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne()
    private Person person;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "town")
    private String town;

    @Column(name = "postcode")
    private String postcode;

    public Address()
    {
    }

    public Address(final String street, final String town, final String postcode)
    {
        this.street = street;
        this.town = town;
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public Person getPerson()
    {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(final Person person)
    {
        this.person = person;
        this.personId = person.getId();
    }

    public String getStreet()
    {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(final String street)
    {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getTown()
    {
        return town;
    }

    public void setTown(final String town)
    {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String getPostcode()
    {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(final String postcode)
    {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

}
```

I would like to map these two entities to the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE address (
    person_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    town VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    postcode VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Note that the address table does not have a primary key, just a foreign key onto the person table. This means that an address cannot exist without a person associated with it and that the mapping must be one-to-one.

Unfortunately, the Hibernate annotations do not work correctly. This is the code I am using to test the above:

```
public static Person save(Person person) {
    SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Integer id = (Integer)session.save(person);
    person.setId(id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return person;
}

@Test
public void testWritePerson() {
    Person person = new Person("Jack", "Bauer", new Address("123 Fake Street", "Springfield", "SP1F 123"));
    person.getAddress().setPerson(person);

    Person savedPerson = PersonTestUtil.save(person);
    assertFalse(
}
```

But the error I get is:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class Address
```

I have tried many permutations of various different annotations without success. Any ideas how I can fix the annotations in the above code so that it correctly persists both Person and Address entities? The full code if you want to test it yourself is here along with instructions on how to set up the database:

https://github.com/alexspurling/hibernate-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution was to remove the "optional = false" attribute from the Person's OneToOne annotation on the address field:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
private Address address;
```

I believe this works because it prevents Hibernate from attempting to persist the Address before the id for the Person has been generated.

Please take a look at the updated github repository for a full working example: https://github.com/alexspurling/hibernate-test

Answer (score 0):

I think the personID field in the Address object should mirror the state of the person object attribute. Try this change to the address entity:

```
public void setPerson(final Person person)
{
    this.person = person;
    this.personId = person.getId();
}
```

You need to make sure when you set one that the other is kept in sync.

**EDIT**
Ok I can see now my suggestion wouldn't work. The basic problem is that you need to set the Id of Address with the Id of Person, but the person ID is auto generated on persist so you don't have that value yet. The Id on Address has no annotation to tell JPA that it is actually a foreign key to Person so it cannot know to set this with the generated person Id.
What you need to do is give JPA enough information so that it knows to save the Person and then use that Id to save the Address. I would try something like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address
{
    //*** Use the Person object to get and set this value
    //*** @Id
    //*** private int personId;

    @Id
    @OneToOne()
    private Person person;
```

Now JPA should have enough annotated information to figure out which order to save the objects and how to set the personId on Address.
Finally the line where you set the Person on the Address in your test case should be moved to the Person constructor as it is an essential step. Without this line JPA won't have the object reference to be able to link the two.

```
public Person(final String firstName, final String lastName, final Address address)
{
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
     this.address = address;
     this.address.setPerson(this);
}
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, I've made that change but I still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks again Ben. I'm not sure why but your suggestion did not work. However I have found a solution that does work which involves simply removing the "optional = false" attribute from the Person's OneToOne annotation on the address field. I've updated the code example in github with this solution (along with a few changes to the tests). If you'd like to take a look and maybe help me understand why this works that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the mapping (anything else is ok). read this

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/

The person is OK

The address should be chaned this way

```
public class Address {

  @Id
  @Column(name="personId", unique=true, nullable=false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
  @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign"
           , parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="person"))
  private int personId;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Person person
  ...
```

When inserting new value, we can set both ends explicitly:

Comment: Hi Vlad, I believe you did not finish your answer but in any case, using those annotations and then assigning the person field on the address object gives exactly the same error. For some reason Hibernate is failing to generate a value for the person_id field.

Comment: On further investigation using your suggested annotations work as does the `@Id` and `@MapsId` annotations I used in my original question. The reason for it failing I've shown in my own answer to this question.